# Magento Custom Extension - Use Product Data

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I want to build a Magento extension in 1.9 which will allow me to list all of the products similar to the 'Catalog -> Manage Products' Grid but I need to add an extra input field for quanitity which is then used to generate a CSV file.

I have created a basic extension thats adds a new option to the navigation menu in the admin panel but I am currently having trouble trying to figure out how to use the product collection as a data source for the adminhtml grid. I have found a tutorial that shows you how to do this for a custom database but nothing for existing data in the Magento tables.

Can anyone give me any advice on the best way of doing this?

Comment: You will need to change the method _prepareCollection in your Grid class to load existing product collection. Have a look at core class for product grid, it will clear many doubts about that, Just don't go too deep, you'll get confused otherwise :)

Comment: @Prateek Do you know a particular class I can look at in the core folder?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid.

Comment: @Prateek Thanks, I will have a look at the class now.